# Getting 'java.lang.AbstractMethodError' error when executing cucumber runner file

Tags: selenium-webdriver, cucumber, testng, pom.xml, ui-automation

Below are the versions I am using:

- junit: 4.12
- cucumber-junit : 7.3.4
- cucumber-testng : 7.13.0
- selenium-java : 4.12.1
- cucumber-java : 7.13.0
- selenium-java : 4.12.1

**Below is the error I am getting
java.lang.AbstractMethodError Receiver class io.cucumber.junit.JUnitCucumberOptionsProvider$JunitCucumberOptions does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract java.lang.Class **uuidGenerator()**' of interface io.cucumber.core.options.CucumberOptionsAnnotationParser$CucumberOptions.

I tried various version , also tried adding serenity and picocontainer

Please help

Comment: If you look at the `cucumber-*` versions you are using you should see the problem.

Comment: should they all must be of same version?

Comment: Yes. The general problem is explained here: https://reflectoring.io/maven-bom/ and if you look at the example project you can see how you only have to declare the cucumber version once https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-java-skeleton/blob/main/maven/pom.xml